# Add more problematic samples to classifier training set

Tags: classification, supervised-learning, train

I have a binary classifier. I can see it systematically makes errors on some types of samples that are not represented in the training set too well. Is it a good idea to get more samples of such data points, add them to the training set and retrain the model? My concern is that it will make training data differ from real distribution. Are some classifiers suite better for it than others (currently I use random forest)?

Comment: Is your dataset unbalanced? That is, when you say "not represented ... too well", do you mean that those example constitute a small proportion of the training set?

Comment: Can you provide more information? This is really broad / vague right now.  I'm not sure how well it can really be answered.

Comment: My dataset is more or less balanced (about 0.4/0.6 split between positive and negative class). The kinds of samples I want to add is really pretty rare in the data so if the samples for training set are randomly extracted from real distributions, the training set should be huge to learn about such kinds of entities

Comment: Suppose I want to classify mushrooms to edible/non-edible. Now I know that purple little smelly mushrooms are usually edible. But they are very rare in the whole mushroom pool (suppose I only have one such sample in my 10k labeled mushrooms set) and there is no way my classifier learn a pattern for those. Is it a good idea to put more samples of small purple smelly mushrooms to my training set (despite the fact that it will make distribution of mushrooms in my training set differ from the real world)?

Comment: And what is your final objective, to detect those rare samples reliably or to have a good overall performance (e.g., as represented by ROC AUC or accuracy or ...)?

Comment: I want to improve positive class precision of the classifier by eliminating the case when it's consistently wrong

Comment: You could try building an ensemble model: train the first classifier normally (as you are doing now), train the second another one just to pick the rare cases (e.g., by assigning larger weights to those rare cases), and train the third only on those instances where the first and the second disagree (also see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193887/classification-with-a-neural-network-when-one-class-has-disproportionately-many/193960#193960)). You can then combine these three to arrive at a single classifier.

Comment: Why would it be a problem if your training data distribution differs form the real distribution? What you should really care about is the boundary between positive and negative samples, and adding more samples of problematic data should help you define the boundary in that region of the feature space better.